# Fine uploader S3 upload without additional policy sign request

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Is there a way to use Fine Uploader to upload to an Amazon S3 bucket by providing the already signed policy document along with the key and the other credentials all at once by overriding the policy post request with our own XML api call?

Our company API returns all the credentials including signed policy for the file in one response and is already well established so setting up a signing page is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for non-chunked uploads since Fine Uploader will only make one request for the signed policy document. However, when uploading files in chunks, the S3 REST API must be used. In that case, a policy document is not used. Instead, a long string of relevant headers for each request must be signed. This signature is then included with the REST call. The headers change with each request, therefore requiring a new signature.

If you want to support chunking and concurrent chunking to S3, you'll need to ensure each request is signed separately via a signature server, or make use of an identity provider to handle this client-side, as demonstrated in our documentation at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/no-server-uploads.html.